# Whats the difference between foo->bar and &foo->bar?

Tags: c

```
1. struct thread_args 
   {
2.   int thread_id;
3.   struct timeval before;
4.   struct timeval after;
   }

5. void * foobar(void *threadargs)
   {
6.   struct * mydata;
7.   mydata = (struct thread_args *) threadargs;

8.   gettimeofday(&mydata->before, NULL);
9.   gettimeofday(mydata->before, NULL);
   }

...
```

What's the difference between lines 8 and 9? The former compiles, the latter does not, but even though the first one compiles I'm not sure that it does what I want.

Comment: [`gettimeofday`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) requires a `struct timeval *` as the first argument, does that give you a clue what the difference is?

Comment: I'm under the impression that the & returns the address of the variable to which the pointer is pointing. I don't see how you can dereference an address.

Comment: Applying the address of operator (`&`) to a type `T` will return a value of type `T*`, which contains the address of the object that you applied `&` to. This value is typically used to initialize/assign a pointer variable of the same type. You're allowed to dereference this value as long as it points to a valid object.

Comment: is it possible to dereference anything else?

Comment: every lvalue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo->bar` = value contained by variable `bar` in struct variable `foo`.

`&foo->bar` = address of variable `bar` in struct variable `foo`.

See this [operator precedence table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

[`gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) requires first argument of type `struct timeval *`. So `gettimeofday(mydata->before, NULL);` does not compile.